# Where is main.js in Nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I want to insert some code before the creation of Vue app.
In vue-cli I could achieve this by just writing some code before the code `createApp(App)` in `main.js`, but how to do this in nuxt3?

Answer (score 0):

There are bunch lifecycle hooks, you can adress - https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/hooks

I believe your would be `builder:generateApp` - https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/blob/main/packages/schema/src/types/hooks.ts#L53